You are in emergency mode
I am new to Linux and I encountered this problem on Pop_os. When pressing ctrl+d I get the same error. I haven't tried anything yet because I am scared to break something. What can I do to get back to normal?

Edit:
I investigated logs with journalctl -xb and here are some errors I found (highlighted in red in system logs):
BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol
[drm] *ERROR* Port F/TC#3: timeout waiting for PHY ready
Failed to insert module 'autofs4': Invalid argument
Same error with modules 'lp', 'ppdev', 'parport_pc', 'msr', 'kyber_iosched'.
Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
nvme0n1: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-block-pop.rules:6 Failed to write ATTR{/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/pci10000:e0/10000:e0:1d.0/10000:e1:00.0/nvme/nvme0/nvme0n1/queue/scheduler}, ignoring: invalid argument
loop4: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-block-pop.rules:2 Failed to write ATTR{/sys/devices/virtual/block/loop4/queue/scheduler}, ignoring: Invalid argument
Same with loop 0-7
FAT-fs (nvme0n1p2): IO charset iso8859-1 not found
Failed to mount /recovery
Failed to mount /boot/efi.


Did you try reading the error message? Did you try doing what the error message tells you to do? What was the result?

The BPF: Invalid name messages would seem to be about Berkeley Packet Filter, which is related to networking and would not be essential for getting the operating system up and running. Pressing Enter should give you command access; Control-D would try and continue the boot process, which won't work until the problem is fixed. The most common problems causing a drop to emergency mode are related to disks and filesystems: press Enter, then run lsblk or cat /proc/partitions so see what disk devices are actually available, and cat /etc/fstab to see which devices the OS expects to find.

On a terminal (ctrl+alt+F4) and sudo dpkg --configure -a

@JörgWMittag Every listed command returns error message except journalctl -xb , which returns logs.

@telcoM I tried running the commands you suggested, here is the result: https://imgur.com/a/XWx0l5J

@PabloA returns the same error message

Analysis
Your imgur screenshot indicates the root filesystem and the encrypted swap have both been successfully activated, so the problem is probably one or more of the remaining file systems listed in /etc/fstab.
The errors you found in the journal have multiple causes:
BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol

This is probably someting only a BIOS update could fix... and probably was always there, you just did not notice that.
[drm] *ERROR* Port F/TC#3: timeout waiting for PHY ready

Something about a display adapter, probably probing for a port that turns out to be not wired in on the motherboard.
Failed to insert module 'autofs4': Invalid argument
Same error with modules 'lp', 'ppdev', 'parport_pc', 'msr', 'kyber_iosched'.
Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.

This is interesting... have you recently installed any updates? An updated kernel package perhaps? Some kernel modules seem to be failing, but none of those should be absolutely critical. Half of these are related to a legacy parallel port (printer port) which practically no modern system has any more.
nvme0n1: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-block-pop.rules:6 Failed to write ATTR{/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/pci10000:e0/10000:e0:1d.0/10000:e1:00.0/nvme/nvme0/nvme0n1/queue/scheduler}, ignoring: invalid argument
loop4: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-block-pop.rules:2 Failed to write ATTR{/sys/devices/virtual/block/loop4/queue/scheduler}, ignoring: Invalid argument
Same with loop 0-7

An udev rule in /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-block-pop.rules is trying to switch the I/O scheduler used for various filesystems... and perhaps doing it in a "noisy" way: it seems to be iterating over all disk-like devices and not caring if the setting is not available for a particular device.
FAT-fs (nvme0n1p2): IO charset iso8859-1 not found
Failed to mount /recovery
Failed to mount /boot/efi.

This might be the most immediate reason why your system is failing to boot: it's trying to mount /recovery and /boot/efi, which are apparently both filesystems of the FAT family (probably specifically FAT32).
But since /etc/fstab does not define an iocharset= mount option for them, the system is trying to mount it using the built-in default I/O character set for FAT-family filesystems: iso8859-1. But apparently the support for it is not available for the kernel: maybe it was configured as a loadable module but the nls_iso8859-1.ko module is not available or has been corrupted somehow. Or maybe the entire ISO8859-1 character support for filesystems was altogether left out of configuration of the newest kernel, because someone assumed every modern filesystem would use UTF-8. (That would be a mistake.)
All of this makes me think something may have gone wrong with the most recent kernel update your system has received. Maybe the initramfs creation process ran out of disk space, and the system is now booting with an incomplete initramfs, or something?
To verify that, run dpkg --list 'linux-image*' to list the currently-installed kernel packages in your system. If there's more than one, find the highest-version one that does not say (meta-package)in theDescriptionfield, and note down in full what itsName` field says. Then search for that name in the package management logs:
grep <kernel package name> /var/log/dpkg.log

replacing <kernel package name> with the full package name you found. This should give you the log entries indicating when that kernel package was installed. If the installation date is just before this problem started, you've probably found the cause.

Workaround
If there is more than one kernel installed, the easiest workaround is to try and boot the system with the second-newest kernel version instead of the newest one. I don't personally use Pop_OS, so this advice will be based on Googling. Pop_OS does not use the most common Linux bootloader GRUB, but instead it seems to use systemd-boot. So the usual procedures involving GRUB will not apply.
At the beginning of the boot process, there should be a simple text-based menu with about four items, and a 10-second or so timeout. It might look like this:
Pop!_OS (pop_os-current.conf)
Pop!_OS (pop_os-oldkern.conf)
Pop!_OS recovery
Reboot Into Firmware Interface

If you don't normally see such a menu, try tapping the SPACE key as soon as you power on the system. Keep tapping it until you see anything that isn't BIOS messages or the manufacturer's logo, and you should get the menu described above.
If only the newest kernel package has the problem, selecting the "old kernel" menu option (Pop!_OS (pop_os-oldkern.conf) or similar) should allow the system to boot more or less normally... for now. But you should not let the system install any further updates until you find out what went wrong, and ideally fix it.
If the system boots to a normal state with the older kernel, open a terminal window and run df -h to see if any filesystem is 100% full or close to it. In particular, if the /boot/efi filesystem is very full, it might be the root cause of this failure. The size of your /dev/nvme0n1p1 partition (which is most likely your EFI System Partition and thus /boot/efi) is only 498M, which might easily be too small for multiple installed kernel versions + their initramfs files.
If booting with an older kernel doesn't help, the Pop!_OS recovery boot option might also be worth trying. However, I have no experience with it, so you should read System76's documentation on it first.

Thank you! Yes, the day before the problem occurred I tried to install an update, however it failed with some errors. I didn't think much of it since it happened before and everything worked as usual. I managed to boot the system with the second-newest kernel version. The /boot/efi and /recovery filesystems are 63% and 70% full. That does not seem very full to me, however I might be wrong. Will installation of new system updates on this kernel version fix something or cause en error once again?

You could try and reinstall just the newest kernel, with something like sudo apt reinstall linux-image-<version number>. If it goes through without errors this time, there is a good chance it will fix the problem. (Perhaps the new kernel plus a number of other updates at the same time caused something to hit 100% full, and now that the package cache has been cleaned after the updates, there should now be plenty of space to manage the kernel update alone.)

As telcoM said in comments, the BPF messages are probably not relevant, and likely caused the real error to scroll off the screen.
Neither action (pressing ctrl-d or enter) is likely to cause damage, but likely won't solve the problem immediately either.  If you are ready to try to repair the system, it wouldn't hurt to try these.
If you press enter, you should be able to explore the system and try to determine the error and possibly (partially) fix it.
The journalctl commands suggested in the error should help review the complete boot log that scrolled off, might expose the real error, probably something about not finding a disk or not finding root disk.
Comparing  lsblk devices available vs fstab expected disks and df to check actually mounted disks can help determine which one failed (if you didn't already find that in the logs).
If the failed disk is not important, you can edit fstab (might have to remount read write first) to comment out the failing disk.  Once that is done, you can exit rescue mode and try a normal boot and then maybe explore the missing disk later.
If the failing disk is important (like the root disk), you may have to do something more difficult to fix it, depending on why it is failing to mount.

You'll need to login with root credentials.
Do try the suggested "journalctl -xb" as it may help.
The BPF messages are part of the kernel log, rather than to boot log, and it appears that you system failed quite early.
It seems likely that your emergency mode is coming from the initrd (initramdisk) and that the regular root was not mounted yet.
The 'mount' command will show you.
IF that's the case you might want to boot a live media for your distro, or else a 'rescue' kernel if present.
